# Skipped 32 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: flutter

The application may be doing too much work on its `main thread`.
Is this any drawback for Application? If it is, Help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that your application is taking too much take to perform a synchronous task. For example if in a build function you have an heavy calculation this can happen.

However, most of the time this happens only in debug mode and should go away if you run in profile mode, try `flutter run --profile` to check that.